# Count number of characters for each line pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am able to count total number of each character in the entire document.

My document:

```
ATATCCCCGGGAT
ATCGATCGATAT
```

Calculating total number of each characters in the document:

```
data=sc.textFile("data.txt")
counts=data.flatMap(lambda x:[(c,1) for c in x]).reduceByKey(add)
```

Result:

```
[(u'A', 7), (u'C', 6), (u'T', 7), (u'G', 5)]
```

My Implementation

```
counts=data.map(lambda x:[(c,1)for c in x])
for row in counts.collect():
    print sc.parallelize(row).reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y).collect()
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: generally try to avoid or minimize ByKey operations for bigger jobs if you can

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
>>> counts.values().sum()
25
```

or

```
>>> sum(counts.collectAsMap().values())
25
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is "Count the number of characters for each line with pyspark" and **not** the total number of each characters for each line, this will do the trick:

```
data.map(lambda x:len(x)).collect()
>>> [13, 12]
```

If you want the index of the line among the number of characters:

```
data.map(lambda x:len(x)).zipWithIndex().collect()
>>> [(13, 0), (12, 1)]
```

Now, to count the number of each character for each line, this may help:

```
def count_occur(str):
   uniq = set(str)
   li = list(str)
   dict = {}
   for key in uniq:
       dict[key] = str.count(key)
   return dict

data.map(lambda x: count_occur(x)).collect()
>>> [{'C': 4, 'T': 3, 'A': 3, 'G': 3}, {'C': 2, 'T': 4, 'A': 4, 'G': 2}]
```

Again, if you want the index of the line `zipWithIndex` do the trick:

```
data.map(lambda x: count_occur(x)).zipWithIndex().collect()
>>> [({'C': 4, 'T': 3, 'A': 3, 'G': 3}, 0), ({'C': 2, 'T': 4, 'A': 4, 'G': 2}, 1)]
```

Hope it helps.